# Jenkins - Build Pipeline - Display more text on Job Names

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, build-automation

I have a Jenkins Build Pipeline similar to the screenshot below:

[image]

Im just wondering is it possible to display the full job name?

As you can see from the screenshot the full name is not displayed at present,

There does not seem to be any settings in Jenkins/Build Pipeline plugin to allow longer names,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the Build Pipeline plugin resolves this issue, see:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin

Ensure Jenkins and the Build Pipeline are on the most up to date versions